# iSight Camera A1023

Tags: hardware, camera

I just acquired a used / old iSight camera A1023 it uses a firewire 400 port. I was wondering if there was a way to connect this to the raspberry pi so I can take pictures with it.

Answer (score 4):

The connection part is easy, just use a [Firewire to USB adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007DNHQPE). The trickier part is finding software that supports this camera. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISight) the driver for the iSight camera is included in Linux kernel 3.0 and up, but this seems to work only for the internal iSight cameras. [This help article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight?action=show&redirect=AppleiSight) describes the process to make the external camera work on Ubuntu, you might be able to do something similar in Raspbian (or get it to work on [the RPI2 version of Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)). It will likely involve some tweaking, and you will need access to a working version of OSX to retrieve the firmware.